# Trying to create and publish a git repository using git API, can't get bash to use my variable in the commands

Tags: string, bash, github

I have a list of Subversion Repositories that I am converting to GIT, and I have an array of SVN repository paths (which is what the range is on my for loop), and I am having it scrap the path so that I just have the repository name (what the `repo_name=${i##*/}` ) is for, and then I have it make what the endgame URL is to be for the repository (the URL variable assignment), then I'm using the git API commands to create on GitHub a repository, which is where my issue is.

I need the `curl --data` command to name the repository what ever the value of `repo_name` is at that moment in the for loop. I guess the issue is that I have a variable inside of the string. I need to get the `repo_name` value to be what it names the repository, because right now it names the repository `-repo_name`.

```
for i in "${svn_repos[@]}";
do
    repo_name=${i##*/}
    url="https://github.com/jjohnson304/${repo_name}.git"

    curl --data '{"name":"${repo_name}"}' -X POST -u jjohnson304 https://api.github.com/user/repos
    git svn clone $i
    git remote add origin ${url}
    git push -u origin master
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are not expanded inside of single quotes. You need to use double quotes for the `--data` argument, with the quotes inside it escaped as `\"`.

```
curl --data "{\"name\":\"${repo_name}\"}" -X POST -u jjohnson304 https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. If I wanted to read up on escaping quotes, anything in particular I should look into?

Comment: See the "Quoting" section in the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).